# Sqlite ускорение работы

Tags: sqlite, запрос

сайт стоит с базой sqlite. Она тормозит и пока нет возможности перенести базу на mysql.
Нашел запрос из-за которого многие проблемы на сайте.Он большой и я не знаю как его ускорить,чтобы сайт работал быстрее. Как ускорить работу на sqllite?Заранее спасибо.

```
SELECT
            test.id      AS 'id',
            test.prefix  AS 'prefix',
            user.id      AS 'user_id',
            variant.id   AS 'variant_id',
            variant.mark AS 'mark'
        FROM test
        INNER JOIN testset
            ON test.id = testset.test_id
            " . (($prefix !== false) ? 'AND test.prefix = :prefix' : '') . "
            AND testset.class_id = :class_id
        INNER JOIN user
            ON user.class_id = :class_id
        LEFT JOIN variant
            ON variant.test_id = test.id
            AND variant.user_id = user.id
        ORDER BY test.prefix, user.name, testset.id
    ")->execute(array(
        'class_id' => intval($classId),
        'prefix' => $prefix,
    ))->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите на [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html)